# Parse XML multi line string in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a multi line XML attribute in Java using the classic DOM. The parsing is working just fine. However, it's destroying the line breaks so, when I render my parsed string, line breaks get replaced by simple spaces.

```
<string key="help_text" value="This is a multi line long
                               text. This should be parsed
                               and rendered in multiple lines" />
```

To get the attribute I'm using:

```
attributes.getNamedItem("value").getTextContent()
```

If I just pass a manually typed string to the render method using "\n", the text gets drawn as intended.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used JDom for this on the past. It saves you a lot of trouble when decoding multilined attributes and really enhances XML parsing/writing on Java. JDom is also compatible with Android development and it's really tiny (only one jar file).

https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom

Comment: I've used the first (and very ugly) "&lt;br /&gt;" solution as a fix for now but I'll look into JDom for sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fsero - can you briefly describe how you managed this with JDom? I've just written a small unit test and newlines in attributes are wiped out in Xerces land even before getting to JDom.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize) the XML parser MUST normalize attribute whitespace, such as replacing a line break character with a space. I.e. if you require line breaks to be preserved you cannot use an attribute value.

In general, whitespace handling in XML is a lot of trouble. In particular, the difference between CR, LF, and CRLF isn't preserved anywhere.

You might find it better to encode newlines in attributes as `&lt;br /&gt;` (that is, the encoded version of `<br />`) and then decode them later.

Comment: @Ben According to XML specification CR/LF combinations MUST be normalized to LF by the XML processor.

Comment: yes precisely. So if the difference matters to your application you must find some other way of encoding it - a special tag of your own make is the ideal method.

Answer (score 2):

From [the XML specifcation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize): 
3.3.3 Attribute-Value Normalization. You will see that all white spaces are normallised to single spaces:

> Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or
>   checked for validity, the XML processor MUST normalize the attribute
>   value by applying the algorithm below, or by using some other method
>   such that the value passed to the application is the same as that
>   produced by the algorithm. All line breaks MUST have been normalized
>   on input to #xA as described in 2.11 End-of-Line Handling, so the rest
>   of this algorithm operates on text normalized in this way.
>
> Begin with a normalized value consisting of the empty string.
>
> For each character, entity reference, or character reference in the
>   unnormalized attribute value, beginning with the first and continuing
>   to the last, do the following:
>
> For a character reference, append the referenced character to the
>   normalized value.
>
> For an entity reference, recursively apply step 3 of this algorithm to
>   the replacement text of the entity.
>
> For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space
>   character (#x20) to the normalized value.
>
> For another character, append the character to the normalized value.