# Replacing newlines in XML attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need some XSLT (or *something* - see below) to replace newlines in all attributes with an alternative character.

I am having to process legacy XML which stores all data as attributes, and uses new-lines to express cardinality. For example:

```
<sample>
    <p att="John
    Paul
    Ringo"></p>
</sample>
```

These new-lines are being replaced with whitespace when I parse the file in Java (as per the XML spec), however I am wishing to treat them as a list so this behaviour isn't particularly useful.

My 'solution' was to use XSLT to replace all newlines in all attributes with some other delimiter - but I have zero knowledge of XSLT. All examples I've seen thus far have either been very specific or have replaced node content instead of attribute values.

I have dabbled with XSLT 2.0's `replace()` but am having a hard time putting everything together.

Is XSLT even the correct solution? With the XSLT below:

```
<xsl:template match="sample/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(current(), '\n', '|')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

applied to the sample XML outputs the following using Saxon:

```
John Paul Ringo
```

Obviously this format isn't what I'm after - this is just to experiment with `replace()` - but have the newlines already been normalised by the time we get to XSLT processing? If so, are there any other ways to parse these values as writ using a Java parser? I've only used JAXB thus far.

Comment: I have a very nasty feeling that I may need to don my rubber gloves and implement a filthy regex on the the XML string prior to parsing. Unfortunately I have no control over the XML being produced.

Comment: Actually no, that would be too horrid to consider.

Comment: If the whitespace within attribute values is semantically significant then you're not dealing with XML, and you'll need to use a non-XML tool to handle it.  [Per spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize) all newlines within an attribute value _must_ be converted to spaces by the parser, and if you want a newline character in the value that you see after parsing then it must be escaped as a character reference (`&#10;`)

Comment: I don't disagree with you. The XML is exported from an application which will remain nameless. It's not _entirely_ the application's fault, although stuffing all data in attributes is a arguably a somewhat dubious approach.  I suspect the users have worked around a lack of 1:M cardinality for this particular field by using newlines which the application blindly exported unadulterated to XML.

Comment: I might do some research into any Java libraries which are designed for dubious XML - this can't be an isolated instance so I'm sure somebody out there has written a deliberately loose / forgiving parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved(ish) the issue by preprocessing the XML with [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) (which is a nod to @Ian Roberts's comment about parsing the XML with a non-XML tool). JSoup is (or was) designed for HTML documents, however works well in this context.

My code is as follows:

```java
@Test
public void verifyNewlineEscaping() {
    final List<Node> nodes = Parser.parseXmlFragment(FileUtils.readFileToString(sourcePath.toFile(), "UTF-8"), "");

    fixAttributeNewlines(nodes);

    // Reconstruct XML
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        output.append(node.toString());
    }

    // Print cleansed output to stdout
    System.out.println(output);
}

/**
 * Replace newlines and surrounding whitespace in XML attributes with an alternative delimiter in
 * order to avoid whitespace normalisation converting newlines to a single space.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This is useful if newlines which have semantic value have been incorrectly inserted into
 * attribute values.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param nodes nodes to update
 */
private static void fixAttributeNewlines(final List<Node> nodes) {

    /*
     * Recursively iterate over all attributes in all nodes in the XML document, performing
     * attribute string replacement
     */
    for (final Node node : nodes) {
        final List<Attribute> attributes = node.attributes().asList();

        for (final Attribute attribute : attributes) {

            // JSoup reports whitespace as attributes
            if (!StringUtils.isWhitespace(attribute.getValue())) {
                attribute.setValue(attribute.getValue().replaceAll("\\s*\r?\n\\s*", "|"));
            }
        }

        // Recursively process child nodes
        if (!node.childNodes().isEmpty()) {
            fixAttributeNewlines(node.childNodes());
        }
    }
}
```

For the sample XML in my question, the output of this method is:

```
<sample> 
    <p att="John|Paul|Ringo"></p> 
</sample>
```

Note that I am not using `&#10;` because JSoup is rather vigilant in its character escaping and escapes *everything* in attribute values. It also replaces existing numeric entity references with their UTF-8 equivalent, so time will tell whether or not this is a a passable solution.

Comment: Note that the downside of using JSoup is that it currently converts attribute names to lowercase. There is an [open bug](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/272) detailing this.

Answer (score 2):

It seem's to be hard to make this. As I found in [Are line breaks in XML attribute values allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449627/are-line-breaks-in-xml-attribute-values-valid) - new line character in attribute is valid but XML parser normalizes it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8188290/1324394) so it is probably lost before processing (and thus before replacing).

Comment: I saw that too, but I was hoping that they'd still be there for some XSLT fix-ups.

I have since found http://jdom.org/ which skirts around the problem by not claiming to be an XML parser, which presumably relieves it of having to comply with the XML spec. Going to give it a shot now...

Comment: Just thinking aloud, you could do something like this `replace(/data/@value, '\s{2,10}','|')` - it is not absolutely correct because it relies that there would be more than one space instead of newline but it could make a job.

Comment: @JirkaŠ. no, that wouldn't work, because the XML parser collapses all consecutive whitespace in attribute values to a single space before the data gets as far as the XPath data model.

Comment: I was afraid about that but I tried in Altova and it worked. Might be it is just Altova specificity.

Comment: Ah, I see I missed the crucial sentence in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize): "All attributes for which no declaration has been read SHOULD be treated by a non-validating processor as if declared CDATA." - so if you don't have a DTD the parser will replace newlines with spaces but _won't_ collapse consecutive spaces to a single space.

Comment: Re: JDom investigation - despite an explicit indication to the contrary at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10439549/1239406, attributes are normalised by Xerces even before getting to JDom.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT only sees the XML after it has been processed by the XML parser, which will have done the attribute value normalization.

I think that some XML parsers have an option to suppress attribute value normalization. If you don't have access to such a parser, I think that doing a textual replace of (\r?\n) by `&#x0A;` prior to parsing might be your best escape route. Newlines that are escaped in this way don't get splatted by attribute value normalization.

Comment: Thanks Michael. After doing a reasonable amount of digging, I'm coming up with blanks trying to find a Java-based parser which allows for suppression of attribute value normalisation. Textual replacement is difficult as I have no control over the XML being produced. This means that I can't limit the replacement to attribute values.